# All subsequences of a string of length n

Tags: algorithm

Given a string of length 'n'. How do I get all the sub sequences of length r(r<=n).
I was thinking of doing it using dynamic programming but could not come up with a good solution.
 I want a pseudo code for this.

Eg. given the string "abc" and r = 2.

OUTPUT : ab
         ba
         ac
         ca
         bc
         cb

thanks in advance

Comment: With a loop?  There are only `n-r+1` such subsequences.

Comment: contigous or noncontigous subsequences?

Comment: I mean all npr  permutations.

Comment: nPr = [The number of ways of obtaining an ordered subset of k elements from a set of n elements](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Permutation.html)

Comment: yes, a list containing npr no of strings should be the output

Comment: I don't think ba is subsequence of abc

Answer (score 3):

It is important to see the difference between all possible substrings (contiguous sequence) and generally subsequences (not necessarily contiguous).

If this is true, then what you were asked is called [combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinations), and it is nice first to estimate how many of them you have given the length of your string and the size of your subsequence.

A recursive algorithm is the best approach here: it allows you to have a the length of your subsequence as a variable. You will find a perfect answer in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n) here.

Comment: I wouldn't say that a recursive algorithm is the "best" approach; it's perhaps the most obvious.  If the strings are very long, then a recursive approach will lead to a stack overflow.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth This is the common drawback of every recursive algorithm, not specifically of this one, as confirmed by the name of this site, by the way :-)

Comment: IMO a recursive algorithm is a good starting point to find a solution to a problem. After finding the recursive solution it always can be transformed into a iterative solution (if this is for any reason necessary).

Comment: @ChristianAmmer From my experience of job interviews they often ask the questions that imply first deriving a recursive algorithm with subsequent discussion on its pros and contras and, on request, its transformation to an iterative one.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code(no pseudo code but understandable, I hope):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

string S;
int n;
vector<string> L;


void F(int index, int length, string str)
{
  if (length == 0) {
    L.push_back(str);
  } else {
    for (int i = index; i < n; i++) {
      string temp = str;
      temp += S[i];
      F(i + 1, length - 1, temp);
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  S = "abcde"; // replace with your string
  n = S.length();
  int k = 3; // or what you want
  F(0, k, string(""));

  int count = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < int(L.size()); i++) {
    string temp = L[i];
    sort(temp.begin(), temp.end());
    do {
      cout << temp << endl;
      count++;
    } while (next_permutation(temp.begin(), temp.end()));
  }


  cout << endl << "count = " << count << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void combinations(String suffix,String prefix){
            if(prefix.length()<0)
                      return;
            System.out.println(suffix);
            for(int i=0;i<prefix.length();i++) {
                 combinations(suffix+prefix.charAt(i),prefix.substring(i+1,prefix.length()));
        }
    }


//call above function like: combinations("","abcd");
```